# How to customize vtkTextActor display font(VTK 6.1)

Tags: c++, fonts, vtk

As we know, VTK text supports 3 kinds of fonts, they are VTK_ARIAL, VTK_COURIER and VTK_TIMES. But in this case, I'd like to customize the text font.

Now, all things I did are:

```
vtkTextActor* textActor = vtkTextActor::New();
//...  
vtkUnicodeString u = vtkUnicodeString::from_utf16((const    vtkTypeUInt16*)txt);     
textActor->SetInput(u.utf8_str());      
//...    
vtkTextProperty* prop = textActor->GetTextProperty();    
prop->SetFontFamily(VTK_FONT_FILE);     
prop->BoldOff();
prop->ItalicOff();  
prop->ShadowOff();  
prop->SetLineSpacing(1.2);     
//...    
prop->SetFontSize(iFontSize);  
prop->SetFontFile(font_file_full_path);
```

There are lots of fonts(true type fonts) installed on my system, above codes only can work for some fonts with specified font size. Such as, it supports 
'Calibric' font with file size 8, 14,16..., but if you set iFontSize to 12, vtk cannot display the string.

So my questions is that does vtk 6.1 not support all kinds of true type fonts installed on my system? If that's the case, is there any function I can use to check if one font/fontsize is supported or not?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Is anybody know this issue?